# Building multiple projects into one directory in VS and/or .NET Core

Tags: dotnet

I've got a project which consists of a number of executables and a lot of common libraries. Also lots of NuGet dependencies involved.

I want to output them into one folder. 
How to be sure that all of these executables are using compatible NuGet libraries and can be put into one folder?

For now I wrote a small node.js snippet which analyzes project.lock.json and finds referenced libraries of different versions. Well it's rather hard and it requires some projects to reference libraries just to fix versions.

Is there a better way? Can I somehow create a meta project which will resolve everything by itself for me?
Is it ok to build solution executables sharing same libs into one folder? (I don't think so)

Comment: What is your purpose for outputting them into one folder? Is it for a new project? Is it for repository organization?

Comment: One self contained .NET Core project might have 50 files. Another one 55. 48 might have same names. So I need a way to understand if 48 are actually same version or not.

Comment: Thank you for posting a question. Could you modify the question so that it contains the attempts you have done in order to solve the issue?